# Filter on nested array with jmespath (using az cli)

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

I would like to know if a value in a TXT record is already available in the DNS:

```
az network dns record-set txt show -g myresourcegroup -z 'mydomain' -n 'mytxtvalues'
```

This is the part of the json result where it's all about:

```
 "txtRecords": [
    {
      "value": [
        "abc"
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": [
        "def"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I tried many queries. These are 2 which I expected to work.

```
az network dns record-set txt show -g myresourcegroup -z 'mydomain.com' -n 'mytxtvalues' --query txtRecords[?value[?starts_with(@, 'abc')]]

az network dns record-set txt show -g myresourcegroup -z 'mydomain.com' -n 'mytxtvalues' --query txtRecords[*].value[?starts_with(@, 'abc')]]
```

The result is:

> *At line:1 char:123
>   + ...  'mytxtvalues' --query txtRecords[?value[?starts_with(@, 'abc') ...
>   +                                                                 ~ Unrecognized token in source text. At line:1 char:124
>   + ... 'mytxtvalues' --query txtRecords[?value[?starts_with(@, 'abc')] ...
>   +                                                                 ~ Missing argument in parameter list.*

It looks like the @ used to filter the array is not recognized. But I don't know how to query otherwise.

What would be a correct query to know if value abc is already in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the command like this:

```
az network dns record-set txt show -g myresourcegroup -z 'mydomain.com' -n 'mytxtvalues' --query "txtRecords[*].value[?starts_with(@, 'abc')]"
```

And if you just need to output the string you can append the parameter `-o tsv`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ah quotes around it. Ok. Thanks!